# Restrict annotation @Notnull and @Size cannot take effect in Spring Bean

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc

I want to use annotation to check bean's property, but `@NotNull` and `@Size` annotation don't take effect. please see my code below:

Spitter bean:

```
package spittr.data;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

public class Spitter {

    private int id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=5, max=25)
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=2, max=30)
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=2, max=30)
    private String lastName;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    } 

    public String toString()
    {
        return "id:" + id + "\n" +
               "firstName:" + firstName + "\n"+
               "lastName:" +lastName+"\n"+
               "password:" + password;
    }
}
```

SpitterController:

```
package spittr.web;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import spittr.data.Spitter;
import spittr.data.SpitterRespository;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/spitter")
public class SpitterController {

    private SpitterRespository spitterRespository;
    public SpitterRespository getSpitterRespository() {
        return spitterRespository;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setSpitterRespository(SpitterRespository spitterRespository) {
        this.spitterRespository = spitterRespository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/register", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showRegistrationForm(Model model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("spitter",new Spitter());
        System.out.println("SpitterController.showRegistrationForm is called");
        return "registForm";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/register", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processRegistration(@Valid Spitter spitter, Errors errors)
    {
        if (errors.hasErrors())
        {

            return "registForm";
        }
        System.out.println("SpitterController.processRegistration is called");
        System.out.println(spitter.toString());
        spitterRespository.saveSpitter(spitter);

        return "redirect:/spitter/"+spitter.getId();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/{userId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showSpitterProfile(@PathVariable("userId") String userId, Model model)
    {
        System.out.println("SpitterController.showSpitterProfile is called");
        Spitter spitter = spitterRespository.findSpitterById(userId);
        model.addAttribute("Spitter",spitter);
        return "userprofile";
    }
}
```

registForm.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sf" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"  %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Register</h1>
<sf:form method="POST" modelAttribute="spitter">
User ID: <sf:input  path="id" /><sf:errors path="id" />   <br />
First Name: <sf:input  path="firstName" /><sf:errors path="firstName" />  <br/>
Last Name: <sf:input  path="lastName" /><sf:errors path="lastName" /> <br/>
Password: <sf:input  path="password" /><sf:errors path="password" /> <br/>

<input type="submit" value="Register" />
</sf:form>
</body>
</html>
```

the effect that I click on Register button:

[image]

If I type some number in the ID field and keep the others as empty, the validation will be passed, but I think I have set `@NotNull` and `@Size` annotation on the Spitter bean, so it's not reasonable for spring to verify it successfully and jump to another page. but in fact, it does, what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Have you enabled bean validation in the spring configuration? Do you have a bean validation implementation (hibernate validator, typically) in your dependencies?

Comment: Can you try `public String processRegistration(@Valid @RequestBody Spitter spitter, Errors errors)`?

Comment: In your Entity add this annotation   @NotEmpty(message = "password is Required")

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to use `@Validated` annotation, instead of `@Valid` in this line:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/register", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String processRegistration(@RequestBody @Validated Spitter spitter, Errors errors)
```

Comment: I added one more annotation `@ResponseBody`

Comment: @pkont '@Valid' is perfectly fine.

Comment: I also try to use public String processRegistration(@RequestBody @Validated Spitter spitter, Errors errors), but got the same error (HTTP 415) as Malik suggested, can you tell me why?

Comment: I figured it out by adding validation-api-2.0.0.Final.jar and hibernate-validator-6.0.4.Final.jar and all its dependency jars to my WEB-INF/lib folder. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it should resolve the issue :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/register", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String processRegistration(@RequestBody @Valid Spitter spitter, Errors errors)
```

### Update from comment

by-default the content-type is `application/json` and you are sending `contentType="text/html"` which is incompatible. That's why you are getting  `HTTP 415 error "Unsupported Media Type"`.

You can explicitly define the content-type at controller lever like below :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/register", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes="text/html", produces="text/html")
```

Comment: I added the annotation  @RequestBody as you said, but I got HTTP 415 error "Unsupported Media Type", what's the problem?

Comment: Updated question

Comment: thanks Malik, I added this property in my controller, but I still got HTTP 415 error, seems the explicitly define doesn't take effect.

Comment: also use *produces="text/html"* at controller level like I updated answer

Comment: yes, I added consumes="text/html" and produces="text/html" now, but I still get that error, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/register", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processRegistration(@Valid @ModelAttribute("spitter") Spitter spitter,BindingResult bindingResult)
    {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors())
        {

            return "registForm";
        }
        //rest of the code
    }
```

Comment: try to highlight the keywords and be clear with the format it will help to reach out your answer for others. try to give a detailed information about your solution. add your code ,highlight the keywords